# Functional Programming/Optic concept that takes a partial object and returns a "filled in" object using lenses and traversals?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, lenses, monocle-scala

(**Edit** I'm using [monocle-ts](https://gcanti.github.io/monocle-ts/), but if it's not possible with monocle-ts (since the author even says it's just a partial port of the original Monocle for Scala) but if there is something in another optics package for any language, I'm open to porting those ideas to TypeScript.)

Suppose I have a helper type `Partial<A>` such that it represents a record that has some or all, but no non-members, of type `A`. (So if `A = { foo: number, bar: string }` then `Partial<A> = { foo?: number, bar?: string }`) (**Edit** This is Typescript's built-in Partial utility type.)

I begin with

```
interface Parent {
  xs: Child[]
}

interface PartialParent {
  partialxs: Partial<Child>[]
}

declare function fillInTheGaps(x: Partial<Child>):Child
```

Suppose I have composed a lens and traversal composed (`composedTraversal`) so that it focuses on  `partialxs` from `PartialState` and then traverses over it as an array. This would be a `Traversal<PartialState, Partial<Child>>`.

Posit also that I have a `declare const fn = (x:Partial<Child>):Partial<Child>` then I can apply `fn` to all children with `composedTraversal.modify(fn)(partialState)` which will yield a new `PartialState` with `fn` applied to all of the `partialxs`.

Is there some concept that lets me "broaden" or "transform" this traversal into something different so that I could compose the lens and traversal and use `fillInTheGaps` so I can pass in the `PartialState` and get back a `State`?

Ignoring that my syntax is TypeScript, I've added the monocle-scala tag because if this concept exists I imagine it's in the Monocle library and I can translate that knowledge to the library I'm using.

**Edit** The problem motivating this question is I have a form input in a Redux app where a user inputs data but most is not required. The INPUTs are not known at compile-time (they're retried from a RESTful API query) so I cannot represent the model as

```
interface Model {
  foo?: string[]
  bar?: string[]
}
```

Instead, it is represented as

```
interface Model {
  [index:string]: string[]
}
```

I can also fetch a default model from the RESTful server. So I've modeled these as `Parent` (what comes from the server) and `Partial<Parent>` (what represents the user's input in the app).

Before doing some computations, I need to fold in defaults for the missing props. This is my `fillInTheGaps` function referenced above.

The desire was to enforce what this does via types in my code and, because I have a lot of optics already written, reuse some of that. I actually have a lens and traversal written to perform other operations on this data. `myLens.compose(myTraversal).modify(fn)` takes a `Partial<State>` and returns a `Partial<State>` but I was hoping to compose these to end up with a function that takes the partial and returns the whole.

I could obviously just write `const filler: (Partial<State>):State = myLens.compose(myTraversal).modify(fillInTheGaps)` and then throw a `//@ts-ignore` above it and know it would work, but that seems, uh, fragile.

Comment: I know it can't be an Iso since an Iso is supposed to represent a function and its inverse, and you can't get the partial state back from state (you can get *a* partial state back, but not *the* previous partial state).

Comment: "*Suppose I have a helper type `Partial<A>`*" - that would be just [the builtin one](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype), no?

Comment: What are `Lens` and `Traversal`, how are they defined? What library are you using? Please link its documentation.

Comment: Is `PartialChild` a typo where you meant `PartialState`? And how is the latter defined?

Comment: Yes, the built in one. I was trying to make my question a little clearer for people who don't use TS (in case a Scala or Haskell person stopped by) but without having to use nothing but pseudocode. I'll flesh out my question with a link to the library I'm using (it's monocle-ts, a partial port of Scala's Monocle lib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, what you might want is a [Polymorphic Traversal or `PTraversal<S, T, A, B>`](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/0.10/apidocs/arrow-optics/arrow.optics/-p-traversal/index.html).

A `Traversal<S, A>` says, "If I have a function `A => A`, I can use `modify` to obtain a function `S => S` that uses the original function to modify all of the
`A`s that appear in `S`".

By comparison, a `PTraversal<S, T, A, B>` says, "if I have a function `A => B`, I can use `modify` to obtain a function `S => T`", this converts all of the `A`s in `S` to `B`, producing a `T`.

Mnemonically, the type parameters of `PTraversal` are:

- `S` the source of the `PTraversal`
- `T` the "modified" source of the `PTraversal`
- `A` the target of the `PTraversal`
- `B` the "modified" target of the `PTraversal`

`PTraversal`s are useful, because they let you write things such as the following:

```js
PTraversal<Array<A>, Array<B>, A, B>
```

Letting you traverse over an `Array` while changing the type of the elements.

---

In your specific case, you've mentioned having two functions:

```js
declare function fillInTheGaps(x: Partial<Child>):Child
declare function fn(x: Partial<Child>):Partial<Child>
```

These can be composed together to produce a single function:

```js
function transformAndFill(x: Partial<Child>): Child {
   return fillInTheGaps(fn(x)); 
}
```

You'll then need to write a `PTraversal<PartialState, State, Partial<Child>, Child>`.

This would support composing with a `Lens` to make a new `PTraversal` in much the same way that `Traversal` did.

This *should* be doable, I think from your question that if you can convert every `Partial<Child>` in `PartialState` to a `Child` you should be able to make a `State`.

---

`PTraversal` exists in Monocle (the Scala library), but unfortunately it doesn't look like it's made it into `monocle-ts`: So you would unfortunately have to write quite a lot of optics library code in order to support this.

Comment: Apologies in advance if I've misunderstood your question. I'm relatively familiar with Monocle, the Scala library, but I've only got next to no experience of TypeScript.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need. Also it's fortunate. I can finally give back to a library I've taken from :)

Comment: How's that going?